# Singlequote in php replace statement returning an error even though escaped

Tags: php, mysql

I need to replace single quotes in my mysql database and im using a script to do this. It works well with other characters but when it comes to single quotes it doesnt work at all.

```
$sql[$handle]['sql'] = 'UPDATE '.$table.' SET '.$field.' = REPLACE('.$field.',\''.$search[$i].'\',\''.$replace[$i].'\')'
```

I get this error when trying to replace single quotes:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '''','')' at line 1)

This is the string I use to search for the quote: `$search[] = ('\'');`

Comment: Can you post more of your script?

Comment: Would be nice to post some code.
Also, using prepared statements might also be an answer.

Comment: Stop escaping data. Use prepared statements and life will become easier.

Comment: Sure, here it is: $sql[$handle]['sql'] = 'UPDATE '.$table.' SET '.$field.' = REPLACE('.$field.',\''.$search[$i].'\',\''.$replace[$i].'\')';

Comment: As for prepared statements, can you give me an example for this case? I would be very grateful.

Comment: Echo out your SQL and see if it looks like what you're expecting it to look like.

Comment: Try using double quotes to make it easier to read and spot problems: `$sql[$handle]['sql'] = "UPDATE $table SET $field = REPLACE($field,'$search[$i]','$replace[$i]')"` Then it would be easier to find escaping issues.

Comment: You probably have to escape the content of `$search` and `$replace` when creating your query. Try `addslashes($search[$i])` and `addslashes($replace[$i]` instead. Prepared statements are explained here [link](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and `?` placeholders. This example uses the [PEAR DB package](http://pear.php.net/package/DB/redirected).

```
<?php
    // import the PEAR DB module
    require_once("DB.php");

    // connect
    $dsn = "mysqli://tehUserName:tehPassWord@db.example.com/tehDatabase";
    $conn = DB::connect($dsn);

    // note the question marks, `?`, used for the string values
    $statement = 'UPDATE '.$table.' SET '.$field.' = REPLACE(?, ?, ?)';
    $result = $conn->query ($statement, [ $field, $search[$i], $replace[$i] ]);

    // ...
```

The PEAR DB package has been superseded, I think - it's been a while since I've coded PHP - but this snippets demonstrates prepared statements and placeholders.

Without using the PEAR DB package, you should still be able to use prepared statements and placeholders, but I'm not sure. (If someone wants to edit this question to that effect...) See the [article on Prepared Statements on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your `$search` because you are passing a single quote - so when it goes to MySQL, it looks like this: `'''`. Add this:

```
$search[$i] = addslashes($search[$i]);
```

It's even better to use [preparing statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to avoid escaping and SQL injection issues.